# onprogress event not working on xmlHttpRequest Mozilla firefox

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, xmlhttprequest

I am trying to upload image to Laravel 5 using XMLHttpRequest(). The concern is when I try to trace progress to build progress bar on Mozilla firefox using

```
xhr.onprogress = function (event) {
  console.log("Progress: "+event.loaded+ "Total : "+event.total);
};
```

It returns:

```
Progress: 48188 Total : 48188
```

on upload start, where as it just work perfect on Google Chrome,

```
Progress: 13148 Total : 48188
Progress: 24189 Total : 48188
Progress: 48188 Total : 48188
```

what can be the  issue?

Comment: Do you follow this recommendation? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest#Monitoring_progress

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this: [Submit a form with Javascript and handle it with ajaxForm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54379553/submit-a-form-with-javascript-and-handle-it-with-ajaxform/54380187#54380187)

but because there is no upload.php there, you can't test online, you can copy the code to a test.html and put the codes in it, then create a `upload.php` put these simple code in it then you can test it:

```
<?php
function isAjax(){
    return isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && $_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']=='XMLHttpRequest';
}

if(isAjax()){
    var_dump($_FILES);
    exit;
}
```

these codes works fine on my Mac Firefox quantum 64.0.2 (64-bit):
[image: Mac Firefox quantum 64.0.2 (64-bit)]

See this demo:
[jquery-ajax-upload-progress-on-Firefox.gif](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lIpbd.jpg)